# google.elements.newsShow display Time not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I am trying to use google newsShow api to display news in a html app.
Here is the code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google AJAX Search API Sample</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyA5m1Nc8ws2BbmPRwKu5gFradvD_hgq6G0" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
google.load("elements", "1", {packages : ["newsshow"]});

function onLoad() {
  // Set the display time to 2 seconds, and transition time to 100 ms
  var options = {
    "queryList" : [
      {
        "title" : "indian News",
        "topic" : "n",
        "ned" : "in"
      }
    ],
    "displayTime" : 1000,
    "transitionTime" : 50
  }
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  var newsShow = new google.elements.NewsShow(content, options);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code was working fine until yesterday.
However this morning the display time is not working at all.

I referred to the example provided in this link,
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#timer_options

here too its not working, I remember very well how the news would get updated according the transition time.

I have tried all these things,
1. closed the browser n started again
2. restarted the system
3. checking the example on other desktops.

Yet nothings working.
Totally unaware whats happening.

Could anyone help,

Thanks for ur time!!

Answer (score 0):

Google abandoned "newsshow". It had been deprecated for a long time but a few weeks ago newsshow just stopped working. I had to scramble to build a replacement for my sites.

Here is a Google News RSS replacement that in many ways is better:

http://www.gooplusplus.com/news-frame-guide.html

See this forum thread:

http://hypercube.us/forum/index.php?topic=1501.0